# how to group observations in stata

Tags: syntax, command, stata

I'm a beginner with stata so this question might be easy for some of you. 
I have a Dataset with Firmspecific data. One variable is `Branche` which contains the following lines of business: `Consumer`, `Utilities`, `Food/Beverage`, `Technology`, `Logistics/Transportation`, `Retail`, `Insurance` etc.
Now I want to form groups, for example the group `Consumer` which should contain `Retail, Food/Beverages, Consumer` but with the command generate `Consumer = Consumer Retail Food/Beverages` it doesn't work. Does anyone know what the right command would be? Thanks!

Comment: When I began using Stata in a serious way, I started by reading my way through the _Getting Started with Stata_ manual relevant to my setup. Chapter 18 then gives suggested further reading, much of which is in the _Stata User's Guide_, and I worked my way through much of that reading as well. Stata supplies exceptionally good documentation that amply repays the time spent studying it. The path I followed surfaces the things you need to know to get started in a hurry and to work effectively.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski   thanks for your advice. I already bought the book "Microeconometrics using Stata" but its hard to understand if your not a native english speaker plus don't know much about statistics programs as I never had to work with them..

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look up intro to Stata videos on YouTube or something similar to get a basic understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user-written string recode command `strrec`:

```
ssc install strrec
strrec Branche ("Consumer" "Retail" "Food/Beverage" = 1 "Consumer"), gen(trunk)
```

You will need to add additional categories as you see fit. This creates a new variable, trunk, that has labeled integer(s).

You can refer to particular trunks like this:

```
list if trunk == 1
list if trunk == "Consumer":trunk
```

The reason I used an integer with value labels rather than a string is that some of the panel data commands do not like string IDs. I am guessing you are headed that route.

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want to built a second group it says that the variable 'trunk' is already allocated. Can I command
strrec Branche ("Automobile" "Construction" "Industrial" "Basic Resources" = 2 "Manufactoring"), gen(Manufactoring)      instead of "gen(trunk)" ? And is the "=2" right? because if I use the 1 again, it would be the same as the category 'Consumer', wouldn't it? Sorry if this is a dumb question but it's hard for me to understand

Comment: Ok the "=2" is wrong it can also be "=1", I get it now, but the rest is right, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: @GiuliaMariaWagner You need to do it in one step: `strrec Branche ("Consumer" "Retail" "Food/Beverage" = 1 "Consumer") ("Automobile" "Construction" "Industrial" "Basic Resources" = 2 "Manufactoring"), gen(trunk)`. Type `help strrec` to see some helpful examples.

Comment: @GiuliaMariaWagner Did this help?

Comment: @GiuliaMariaWagner You should click on the checkmark on the left to select this as the answer.

Comment: @Dimitry Do you know how to destring the observation? For example I want to change `Consumer` into `1`, `Manufacturing` into `2` and so on. The destring command doesn't work here because it's not a variable, but I don't know how to fix the problem, can you please help me?

Comment: You cannot use `destring` since you don't have a string variable. You have an integer (1,2,...,k) that has value labels attached. You can either not create value labels in `strrec` or you can drop them with `label drop trunk`.

Comment: @GiuliaMariaWagner This is not a programming question, but a math or statistical one, so it is off topic here (especially as a comment on a non related question). Google "dummy variable trap" first, and only then post a question on CrossValidated or Statalist. Make sure to read and comprehend the rules of each forum before posting.